# Drools reference static field

Tags: java, static, drools, mvel

I wish to make a reference to a static field present in a java class from within the when clause of a drool. I don't want to insert a fact representing this value, because the value is related to our system rather than our business logic. Specifically, it is for logging purposes.

The link below seems to suggest that referring to a static variable from within a drl file is possible. Obviously this will work from the then clause. Is it possible to also refer to this value in a when clause? Keep in mind I prefer not to use eval statements as I understand they are a tool of last resort.

http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Access-a-static-variable-from-Java-file-to-DRL-File-td4023641.html

**UPDATE:**

Below is the code I need to fit the static call into. Basically, the drool should only fire if the log level is of a certain value.

Java class:

```
public class LoggingUtilities{
public static LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.NONE;
}
```

drl file:

```
import com.myproject.LoggingUtilities;
rule "MyRule"
when
  MyFact()
then
    Log.writeOut("Some Stuff");
end
```

Comment: Who says that "eval" is deprecated? Truth is, that recent versions of Drools don't require you to use eval within a pattern since general boolean expressions are possible now.

Comment: In-line evals are explicitly deprecated in docs. http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html

Maybe I just mentally deprecated other eval statements in order to make sure I never used them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Java class `a.b.Foo` has a public static field `bar`, you should

```
import a.b.Foo;
```

and then you simply use

```
when
   SomeFact( ... Foo.bar ... )
```

in the context of some constraint expression.

If you have problems, provide full DRL code of that rule and the minimum snippet for that Java class.

**Later**

According to your example:

```
import com.myproject.LoggingUtilities;

rule "MyRule"
when
   MyFact()
   eval( LoggingUtilities.logLevel != LogLevel.NONE )
then
    Log.writeOut("Some Stuff");
end
```

This is the Conditional Element (!) `eval`, which remains a first class citizen. It is the "inline" `eval` only which has outlived its usefulness.

** Later **

You can avoid `eval` by creating and inserting a fact with the log level (and other parameters). This would have additional advantages:

1. You can change the log level dynamically.
2. You can block rule evaluation early on *if the single purpose of the rule is logging*.

   ```
   Parameters( logLevel != LogLevel.NONE )
   MyFact()
   ```

Comment: From what I understand, eval statements should be avoided if at all possible because they don't get cached as efficiently by rete as would using a fact. Is eval really the best option in this situation?

Comment: @melchoir55 If you want to make a reference to a statc field: yes. You might have thought of other options - see my second addition.